# case statement issues in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am writing a small case statement in sql query as follows:

```
 SELECT [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].SYS_ID,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].NODE_ID,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].NODE_EQ_NO, 
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].EQ_TYPE,
        CASE EQ_TP_OFFSET
          WHEN 'MULTIPLE' THEN '1'
          WHEN 'SINGLE' THEN '0'
        END AS EQ_TP_OFFSET,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].VAR_NAME,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].VAR_SET,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].VAR_SUBSET, 
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_NODE_ID, 
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_NODE_VAR_ID,
        CASE RHS_RELN
          WHEN 'EQ' THEN '0'
          WHEN 'LE' THEN '1'
          WHEN 'GE' THEN '2'
          WHEN 'MIN' THEN '3'
          WHEN 'MAX' THEN '4'
        END AS RHS_RELN,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_OBJECT,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_VAR_TYPE,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_TP_OFFSET,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].TIME_PRD,
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].RHS_VALUE,  
        [##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS].SUB_NET_ID, 
        CASE RHS_OBJECT
          WHEN 'OBJECTIVE' THEN 'OBJECTIVE'
        END AS FUNC_NAME 
   FROM ##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS;
```

I am getting error cannot convert varchar value 'multiple' to data type int...any help.?
i am not sure why i am getting this error though i have put one ''.

Comment: You'll get more help if it takes less effort to read what you've posted.  That, and include pertinent details like the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `[##OT_NET_EQUATIONS_RHS_IDS]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `EQ_TP_OFFSET` is an `int`, so when Sql Server is evaluating the `CASE`, it tries to compare `'MULTIPLE`' to the value of `EQ_TP_OFFSET` and cannot convert it to an `int`.

Looking at it again, I'm thinking perhaps `EQ_TP_OFFSET` is an `int` and you meant to code the `case` to select a value more meaningful than `1` and `0`.  Perhaps it should be the other way around?

```
CASE EQ_TP_OFFSET 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE'  
    WHEN 0 THEN 'SINGLE' 
END AS EQ_TP_OFFSET
```

Same would go for `RHS_RELN`.